# Differentiate between data tags in custom villager trading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do/can I make it so that when making custom villager summon commands to spawn in villagers with certain trades such as this one:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:5,Damage:2,Count:4},sell:{id:5,Damage:4,Count:12}}]}}
```

So that these villagers can differentiate between data tags, durabilities, etc...?
This command (just an example) is supposed to trade 4 birch planks for 10 acacia planks -- but you can in fact put in ANY 4 planks to get the acacia planks (including acacia planks).

How do/can I make it so that the villager is strict in only allowing birch planks for trade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, as reported on the [official Minecraft Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-349).

It was reported as fixed in 14w02a (9/1/14) but reopened yesterdat (8/2/14), so no new date for fixing has been given. However, given that the bug was fixed once before, it is highly likely it will be fixed again soon.